# How to use in-memory-web-api and real service API in Angular5 application

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient, angular-in-memory-web-api

I am facing issue when am using in-memory-web-api with real api. when i am calling post call its not triggering it's looking in in-memory-web-api. I want to use in-memory-web-api for some pages because still my rest api is not ready. Some pages i got real service API. when I am integrating the real service its not triggering. After some long analysis i found out because of the in-memory-web-api is not working. Let me know if any way to use both in Angular5 application.

```
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

//import Section    

import { LocaldatasericeService }  from './localdataserice.service';
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
  LocaldatasericeService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
)
```

Another one service.js I am calling the real post call.

```
getTables(): Observable<any[]> {
   let parser = new DOMParser();
   let xmlString ='<stp><parameters><selFilter>V</selFilter></parameters></stp>';
   let doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");
   return this.http.post<any[]>('http://blabla.phs.org:7980/SASBIWS/rest/storedProcesses/Web/hsd3_hsd_pcp_try_111/dataTargets/_WEBOUT',doc,httpOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After adding passThruUnknownUrl: true in below configuration of app.module.ts it's started working.

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
      ....
      HttpClientModule,
      ...
      HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
        LocaldatasericeService,{ dataEncapsulation: false,
        passThruUnknownUrl: true }
      )
      ...
  ]
```